Compilation Process LuaLaTeX: Flow Chart
I am searching for a flow chart of the compilation process for LuaLaTeX.
The scheme should include processing of directlua commands, the luacode environment. Furthermore, I use \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", mycount, "mycount")}} functionality.

it's not really clear what diagram you expect. \directlua is an expandable primitive so executes at the same point as other expandable tex commands. Each of the callbacks is called at a distinct point as documented for each callback.  luacode isn't a luatex primitive it's an enviornment defined in a latex package, just setting up catcodes and has no special compilation steps

Any diagram. @David Carlisle

I am not sure I can think of any reasonable diagram. Callbacks as the name suggests are functions inserted into the inner code to call back to user supplied functions, each callback happens at a different stage at whatever places the luatex developers found having a customisation possibility useful. The callback you mention `process_unput_buffer_ is called at a very early stage, as tex is reading characters from the file, before they are tokenised, other callbacks work on already typeset lists, related to line breaking etc, or to writing error messages etc.

I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you already know how LuaLaTeX processes the input and you want to make a diagram of your knowledge but you don't know how to draw diagrams? Or is the processing chain unclear to you and you think a diagram might make it more clear to you? Or do you want a diagram for one specific document that you have instead of the general case? Or are you just curious if such a diagram already exists or if someone is willing to make it, and if so, why?

I need a general diagram demonstrating how lualatex works. @Marijn

@Youra_P what do you want to do with such a diagram? Is there anything in particular that you currently don't understand about the processing flow?

I thought that such a scheme already exists, but I can't find it. @Marijn
